# No puedo hacer que los datos se comparen con los de la base de datos!

Tags: base-de-datos, login, backend, registro

Como estan? queria hacerles una consulta. Hoy intente hacer un inicio de sesion, pero a la hora de querer ingresar a traves del lado de login.php me recarga la pagina, no me envia a la pagina principal. Los datos si se guardan en la lista de php, pero se ve que a la hora de compararlos, no lo hace. Agradezco su ayuda!`

```
<?php
  session_start();

  require 'database.php';

  if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, email, password FROM users WHERE id = :id');
    $records->bindParam(':id', $_SESSION['user_id']);
    $records->execute();
    $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $user = null;

    if (count($results) > 0) {
      $user = $results;
    }
  }
?>
```